# ESX Compact Flash

Tags: hardware, vmware-esx

I am planning on putting ESX on a compact flash media and making it bootable these will be running on high-performace servers. My question is:

Is CF a good idea and if so what CF read/write speed should I be looking for ESX specifically?

Currently looking at this for the reader:

http://www.lycom.com.tw/ST138.htm

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably better off with ESXi, as that's much closer to how it's intended to be run.

Comment: Not if you want a service console. Which can be very, very useful. But, of course, ESXi is also free...

Comment: IMO, anyone banking too much into ESX now is asking for trouble. ESX is going away, so we're all going to need to figure out how to live with ESXi.

Comment: The Service Console is indeed handy, but it's far less powerful than the VI/vSphere Client.  Even if you don't spring for vCenter (where you can manage everything under one console), the Client is far more powerful than the Service Console.  The only case where I've needed the Service Console was to ssh in to check /var/log.

Comment: I disagree: there are things you can do in the SC that you *can't* do in the Client. Try manually editing a .vmx file.

Comment: I'll give you that, Massimo.  Slipped my mind; that was a core part of our build process because of the imaging process we used...

Answer (score 3):

The CF will only be used to boot ESX, so it won't affect VM performance at all. It is indeed a documented and supported scenario to install and run ESX(i) this way.

Comment: So ESX is loaded entirely into memory then?

Comment: I agree with the commenter below you really want to install ESXi because ESX is going away.

Comment: ESX isn't going away anytime soon...

Comment: ESX 4.1 is the last major version of ESX that VMware will release. All future releases 4.whatever, 5 etc will be ESXi only, or as VMware now call it the vSphere Hypervisor. http://www.vmware.com/support/vsphere4/doc/vsp_esx41_vc41_rel_notes.html